# Return filtered records from a returned set of data from two tables

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I have three tables:
- Venue
- Space (belongs to Venue)
- Included Space (belongs to Space)

I receive the id of a Venue in the route and return all the related spaces that I know have Included Spaces(a field called num_included_spaces__c on the Space record that maintains a count of its children). Now that I have all the related parent Spaces for that Venue, I need to find all of the Included Spaces for them.

An Included Space is still a Space, it just happens to have a parent that resides in the same table. I'm trying to turn this:

Venue = Rockdog
- Space = Upstairs
- Space = Media Room
- Space = Courtyard
- Space = Downstairs
- Space = Front Patio
- Space = Indoor Bar

Into this:

Venue = Rockdog
- Space = Upstairs
-- Included Space = Media Room
-- Included Space = Courtyard
- Space = Downstairs
-- Included Space = Front Patio
-- Included Space = Indoor Bar

The Included Spaces table has belongs_to__c and space__c as fields, where belongs_to__c is the id of the parent space and space__c is the id of the child. So i'm looking to find all the Included Spaces where belongs_to_c matches the id of any @spaces returned below

```
@sub_spaces = Space.where("venue__c = ? AND num_included_spaces__c = ?", params[:venue],0)

@spaces = Space.where("venue__c = ? AND num_included_spaces__c > ?", params[:venue],0)
```

How would I write this Active Record Query for @included_spaces?

Answer (score 0):

my database schema.

```
mysql> describe venues;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe spaces;;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| venue_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql> describe included_spaces;;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| space_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Below function will somehow give you the result you need (in console ofcourse ) however it's not a good solution - it queries database more than needed. However it is the easy -))

```
def foo id
  v = Venue.find(id)
    puts v.name
    v.spaces.each do |space|
      puts space.name
      space.included_spaces.each do |spis|
        puts spis.name
      end
    end
end
```

You can also try a more complex query sth like,

```
mysql> SELECT spaces.name, included_spaces.name FROM `spaces` INNER JOIN `venues` ON `venues`.`id` = `spaces`.`venue_id` INNER JOIN `included_spaces` ON `included_spaces`.`space_id` = `spaces`.`id` WHERE `spaces`.`venue_id` = 1
    -> ;
+------------+-----------+
| name       | name      |
+------------+-----------+
| Upstairs,  | Front     |
| Upstairs,  | Patio,    |
| Upstairs,  | Indoor    |
| Upstairs,  | Bar       |
| Downstairs | Media     |
| Downstairs | Room,     |
| Downstairs | Courtyard |
+------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

which should be translated to active record as

```
Space.joins(:venue)
  .joins(:included_spaces)
  .where(venue_id: 1)
  .select('spaces.name, included_spaces.name')
```

Comment: I think I might have asked my question wrong, but your Included Spaces do not have the belongs_to and space fields. It looks as though you are assuming that Included Spaces are not also Spaces, which they are. The Included Spaces is more of a reference of which Spaces have Parents. The added wrinkle is that Neither the Space Table nor the Included Spaces have primary keys that I can work from, so I would have to join both off of foreign keys.

Comment: No, I've declared belongs_to and has_many hierarchically: `Venue` has many `Spaces`, `Space` also has many `Included Spaces`, and `Included Space` belongs to a `Space` and `Space` also belongs to a `Venue`. Maybe you think that way because of you've not seen a FK constraint in table description, that's because I've created them through padrino generators, and I think they've not implemented that functionality to create foreign keys via migration. However nothing but faster querying would be the only change in case if there were FKs declared. BTW, it would be great if you add table structures.